CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. при работе с ruStore sdk
Установил RuStore sdk Сделал все по их инструкциям, выдает ошибку при билде проекта

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
C:\Work\version_uity\2022.3.21f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe
-classpath "C:\Work\version_uity\2022.3.21f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-7.2.jar"
org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m"
"assembleRelease"
Environment Variables: SHIM_MCCOMPAT = 0x810000001
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = AMD64 AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_YELLOWBUCKET_DEV =
48835b4d1f5e342aefe5f016324d296a GATEWAY_VM_OPTIONS =
C:\Users\alex\Downloads\jetbra-ded4f9dc4fcb60294b21669dafa90330f2713ce4\jetbra\vmoptions\gateway.vmoptions
DriverData = C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData USERDOMAIN =
DESKTOP-TMVH9O0 CommonProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files
(x86)\Common Files COMPUTERNAME = DESKTOP-TMVH9O0 DEBUG_ENV_VAR =
UnityHub LOGONSERVER = \DESKTOP-TMVH9O0
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_GREENBUCKET_PROD = yyzPzalJDwrQcYNuOZam0bhKb26WyyhK
PUBLIC = C:\Users\Public ProgramData = C:\ProgramData SESSIONNAME =
Console AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_YELLOWBUCKET_PROD =
Ph-837Q6GNodAkyc2MRkxVPUcjlIET4d NVIDIAWHITELISTED = 0x01 Path =
C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware
Workstation\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program
Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA
Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client
SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files
(x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit;C:\Program
Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\110\Tools\Binn;C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts;C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311;C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program
Files\JetBrains\PyCharm
2023.3\bin;;C:\Users\alex.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
APPDATA = C:\Users\alex\AppData\Roaming RIDER_VM_OPTIONS =
C:\Users\alex\Downloads\jetbra-ded4f9dc4fcb60294b21669dafa90330f2713ce4\jetbra\vmoptions\rider.vmoptions
windir = C:\Windows AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_REDBUCKET_DEV =
46b8b46515e7632fc42a504b72e05fd0 ProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files
(x86) ProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files OS = Windows_NT ANDROID_NDK_ROOT
= C:\Work\version_uity\2022.3.21f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK
DATAGRIP_VM_OPTIONS =
C:\Users\alex\Downloads\jetbra-ded4f9dc4fcb60294b21669dafa90330f2713ce4\jetbra\vmoptions\datagrip.vmoptions
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER = Intel64 Family 6 Model 154 Stepping 3,
GenuineIntel HEAP_CLIENT_TOKEN_STAGING = 3786794399 HOMEPATH =
\Users\alex SystemRoot = C:\Windows FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING =
Default CLION_VM_OPTIONS =
C:\Users\alex\Downloads\jetbra-ded4f9dc4fcb60294b21669dafa90330f2713ce4\jetbra\vmoptions\clion.vmoptions
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_REDBUCKET_DEV = U4PSN7S7PuYVRODivvdcFwbu8R6IHGqa
CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME = \.\pipe\crashpad_19736_UYXXVFKJNMNRMFEJ
PROCESSOR_LEVEL = 6 JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
CommonProgramFiles = C:\Program Files\Common Files PyCharm =
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2023.3\bin; PT8HOME = C:\Program
Files\Cisco Packet Tracer 8.2.2 JETBRAINS_CLIENT_VM_OPTIONS =
C:\Users\alex\Downloads\jetbra-ded4f9dc4fcb60294b21669dafa90330f2713ce4\jetbra\vmoptions\jetbrains_client.vmoptions
DEVECOSTUDIO_VM_OPTIONS =
C:\Users\alex\Downloads\jetbra-ded4f9dc4fcb60294b21669dafa90330f2713ce4\jetbra\vmoptions\devecostudio.vmoptions
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE = DESKTOP-TMVH9O0 TEMP =
C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Temp ProgramFiles = C:\Program Files
CommonProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files\Common Files RUBYMINE_VM_OPTIONS
= C:\Users\alex\Downloads\jetbra-ded4f9dc4fcb60294b21669dafa90330f2713ce4\jetbra\vmoptions\rubymine.vmoptions
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_YELLOWBUCKET_DEV = wKi8foVigDditGFvmZewRFWsEbX9Y0YO
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_GREENBUCKET_DEV = 3ded2a762163603391a425f688f990c8
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_REDBUCKET_PROD = ca12bb461ea96f9bdf5df4ded7d52994
APPCODE_VM_OPTIONS =
C:\Users\alex\Downloads\jetbra-ded4f9dc4fcb60294b21669dafa90330f2713ce4\jetbra\vmoptions\appcode.vmoptions
HOMEDRIVE = C: AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_STAGING =
83ee04fccc67e4fcc7dd527c4c6f1e21 USERNAME = alex OneDrive =
C:\Users\alex\OneDrive AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_YELLOWBUCKET_PROD =
e03a9bbe92dc38a88cdb068d24c65b46 IGCCSVC_DB =
AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAA9nOGknKJ00iwzanWGay1jAQAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAACVcebIm/jg/5dTSGitb8f8jcUzX7jGoVA9PkX1lcMDlgAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAADvbXd7Ezrc6iogWBwtWHvy2WpNmpgsSqeCdlGnQDK0QmAAAAAsI8hMS5XHtQ72hNBB3kpLQs0BKzcCJ9VcF6i8j4VGRB3wbLo8vUjKjfPc2L/X7fh3Ijk7MR8EbwLLTo9XZUsoYtaTlcBh1crP9LatlcEQLuXHsk1QBR8MiTTgVaC8XM1AAAAAdQ1nREEDpkDCcMf8A0eqwTdUWc8eDnjsMlrNwAvbz60aJt0hGNgjiVmiqa2PXZuX0qRpmE117CI/amcqbCX0kQ==
PATHEXT = .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_REDBUCKET_PROD = QqyoFpcWPi7V17p80_46CF6-sNGRGbHo
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS = 12 PHPSTORM_VM_OPTIONS =
C:\Users\alex\Downloads\jetbra-ded4f9dc4fcb60294b21669dafa90330f2713ce4\jetbra\vmoptions\phpstorm.vmoptions
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_GREENBUCKET_DEV = 84H2gMm_FJzhr3mBaX1lM1JVukmCM7d9
WEBIDE_VM_OPTIONS =
C:\Users\alex\Downloads\jetbra-ded4f9dc4fcb60294b21669dafa90330f2713ce4\jetbra\vmoptions\webide.vmoptions
PYCHARM_VM_OPTIONS =
C:\Users\alex\Downloads\jetbra-ded4f9dc4fcb60294b21669dafa90330f2713ce4\jetbra\vmoptions\pycharm.vmoptions
AMPLITUDE_DEPLOYMENT_KEY_RED_BUCKET_DEV =
client-wbjHYrmeSR87GmWOE7LDpf7sUySOIKHm GOLAND_VM_OPTIONS =
C:\Users\alex\Downloads\jetbra-ded4f9dc4fcb60294b21669dafa90330f2713ce4\jetbra\vmoptions\goland.vmoptions
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_GREENBUCKET_PROD = c86fea37a9e1d3f0878b96e15b111c7c
ComSpec = C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe WEBSTORM_VM_OPTIONS =
C:\Users\alex\Downloads\jetbra-ded4f9dc4fcb60294b21669dafa90330f2713ce4\jetbra\vmoptions\webstorm.vmoptions
ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = undefined ZES_ENABLE_SYSMAN = 1
PROCESSOR_REVISION = 9a03 BURST_ANDROID_MIN_API_LEVEL = 22 EFC_21936 =
1 JETBRAINSCLIENT_VM_OPTIONS =
C:\Users\alex\Downloads\jetbra-ded4f9dc4fcb60294b21669dafa90330f2713ce4\jetbra\vmoptions\jetbrainsclient.vmoptions
AMPLITUDE_DEPLOYMENT_KEY_RED_BUCKET_PROD =
client-zH8Y7OK1i331EKuG77C6UxN8ygcM6LzS TMP =
C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Temp IDEA_VM_OPTIONS =
C:\Users\alex\Downloads\jetbra-ded4f9dc4fcb60294b21669dafa90330f2713ce4\jetbra\vmoptions\idea.vmoptions
SystemDrive = C: AMPLITUDE_API_KEY = 28f3cae0b33b8b3702120c9ed1a935aa
FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING = Internet Explorer SENTRY_ACCESS_TOKEN
= 3df78d9e53f8456aa90fbae044ce1a6261421ab1d0014674bc2e933477289017 HEAP_CLIENT_TOKEN = 1717415662 ALLUSERSPROFILE = C:\ProgramData
DATASPELL_VM_OPTIONS =
C:\Users\alex\Downloads\jetbra-ded4f9dc4fcb60294b21669dafa90330f2713ce4\jetbra\vmoptions\dataspell.vmoptions
STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS =
C:\Users\alex\Downloads\jetbra-ded4f9dc4fcb60294b21669dafa90330f2713ce4\jetbra\vmoptions\studio.vmoptions
PSModulePath = C:\Program
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
LOCALAPPDATA = C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local USERPROFILE = C:\Users\alex
WOOTRIC_CLIENT_TOKEN = NPS-aa8be4c3
stderr[ Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.RemoteActionCompatParcelizer found in modules
core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and
jetified-androidx.core.core-1.14.0-alpha01-runtime
(:androidx.core.core-1.14.0-alpha01:)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer found in
modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and
jetified-androidx.core.core-1.14.0-alpha01-runtime
(:androidx.core.core-1.14.0-alpha01:)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and
jetified-androidx.core.core-1.14.0-alpha01-runtime
(:androidx.core.core-1.14.0-alpha01:)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and
jetified-androidx.core.core-1.14.0-alpha01-runtime
(:androidx.core.core-1.14.0-alpha01:)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules
core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and
jetified-androidx.core.core-1.14.0-alpha01-runtime
(:androidx.core.core-1.14.0-alpha01:)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and
jetified-androidx.core.core-1.14.0-alpha01-runtime
(:androidx.core.core-1.14.0-alpha01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar found in modules appcompat-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0) and
jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar$DisplayOptions found in modules appcompat-1.2.0-runtime
(androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0) and
jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar$LayoutParams found in modules appcompat-1.2.0-runtime
(androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0) and
jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar$NavigationMode found in modules appcompat-1.2.0-runtime
(androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0) and
jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar$OnMenuVisibilityListener found in
modules appcompat-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0)
and jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar$OnNavigationListener found in modules
appcompat-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0) and
jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar$Tab found in modules appcompat-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0)
and jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar$TabListener found in modules appcompat-1.2.0-runtime
(androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0) and
jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle found in modules appcompat-1.2.0-runtime
(androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0) and
jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$1 found in modules appcompat-1.2.0-runtime
(androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0) and
jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$Delegate found in modules
appcompat-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0) and
jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$DelegateProvider found in
modules appcompat-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0)
and jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$FrameworkActionBarDelegate
found in modules appcompat-1.2.0-runtime
(androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0) and
jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$ToolbarCompatDelegate
found in modules appcompat-1.2.0-runtime
(androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0) and
jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController found in modules appcompat-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0)
and jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$1 found in modules appcompat-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0)
and jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$2 found in modules appcompat-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0)
and jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$3 found in modules appcompat-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0)
and jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$4 found in modules appcompat-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0)
and jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$5 found in modules appcompat-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0)
and jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$AlertParams found in modules
appcompat-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0) and
jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$AlertParams$1 found in modules
appcompat-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0) and
jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$AlertParams$2 found in modules
appcompat-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0) and
jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3 found in modules
appcompat-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0) and
jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$AlertParams$4 found in modules
appcompat-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0) and
jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$AlertParams$OnPrepareListViewListener
found in modules appcompat-1.2.0-runtime
(androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0) and
jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler found in modules
appcompat-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0) and
jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$CheckedItemAdapter found in
modules appcompat-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0)
and jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01:)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$RecycleListView found in
modules appcompat-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0)
and jetified-androidx.appcompat.appcompat-1.7.0-beta01-runtime
(:androidx.ap


Пробовал различные способы, не помог ни один, что можно сделать?
